# How to get href from class using python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

I want to get link from href from an element. I tried find_elements_by_css_selector but can't reach out it. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
<a class="name" title="Download" data-i18n="[title]clickToDownload" data-src="some-link" href="link-to-retreive">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the value of the *href* attribute you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.name[title='Download']").get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='name' and @title='Download']").get_attribute("href"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.name[title='Download']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='name' and @title='Download']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: thanks, Using css_selector solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Call [`get_attribute`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=get_attribute#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) on each of the links:

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('##')
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

OR

```
lnks=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
# traverse list
for lnk in lnks:
   # get_attribute() to get all href
   print(lnk.get_attribute(href))
driver.quit()
```